# Glow buttons with a delay in between

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to light up a sequence of buttons in order with a small delay in between but I just can't figure out how to glow each button separately with a small delay in between without freezing all code.

at this point I got this, which waits a second and for some reason lights up both buttons at the same time after.

The array given to the method contains values from 1-3 referencing one of the 3 buttons in order

```
private func showSequence(sequence: Array<Int>){
        
        for i in  sequence {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.buttonArray[i-1].doGlowAnimation(withColor: .white, withEffect: .big)
            }
        }
}
```

And the glow effect I found online, code:

```
extension UIView {
    enum GlowEffect: Float {
        case small = 0.4, normal = 2, big = 15
    }

    func doGlowAnimation(withColor color: UIColor, withEffect effect: GlowEffect = .normal) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero

        let glowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowRadius")
        glowAnimation.fromValue = 0
        glowAnimation.toValue = effect.rawValue
        glowAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+0.3
        glowAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(0.3)
        glowAnimation.fillMode = .removed
        glowAnimation.autoreverses = true
        glowAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        layer.add(glowAnimation, forKey: "shadowGlowingAnimation")
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a timer to change the state of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks this seemed to do the trick!